# QTP Test Case Execution on Remote Machine

Tags: java, qtp

Is it possible to run QTP test cases from remote machine without installing QTP in it.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not. The machine that's running the test has to have QTP installed on it.

You can orchestrate the test runs from a machine that doesn't have QTP (by using QC) but the machines on which the tests are run must have QTP installed.

Comment: Additionally, you could orchestrate the test run from a machine that does not have QTP using other mechanisms than QC, such as various continuous integration servers kicking off your QTP tests after a successful build. But the key point, as Motti said, is that the machine/vm actually running the test needs to have QTP installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to run test in a machine where QTP is not installed.

Note that even while running Test in Remote machine, the remote machine window should not minimized.

Thanks,

Rekha